# Training Tensorflow object detection model on AWS

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

Tutorial on the github page for Tensorflow object detection API also has information on running the training on Google Cloud Platform.

But I need to run the training on AWS instance. I have the TFRecords files with me. Is there any tutorial etc available for same?Googling doesn't help much.I am new to AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to launch an instance which already has Tensorflow installed on it. AWS has prepared AMIs for that.

see here: https://aws.amazon.com/tensorflow/

Then you just upload anything to the instance and run the script.